# Ellipse given by two variables in this form

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, conic-sections, maxima-minima

I Have tried watching youtube videos and searching it but I havent found any in this form and I am struggling with math.Plus classes are not that great of a help so I decided to post here and see if anyone can help me understand how to deal with this.
-A real function f of two real variables are given by the expression
$$f(x, y) = 13y^2 + 7x^2+6\sqrt{3}xy+4y-4\sqrt{3}x$$

a) Explain that the $0-$level curve for $f$ is an ellipse, and determine the centre of the
ellipse and the semiaxes.
The closed and bounded set of points in the first quadrant of the $(x, y)-$plane that is
bounded by the $0-$level curve for $f$ and the $x-$axis, is denoted $M.$

b) Determine the global maximum and the global minimum of $f$ on $M$ and determine the points in which they are attained.

c) Determine the range of $f$ on $M$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please give some context for this question. Where does the problem come from? What parts of it can you do?  What parts are giving you difficulty?  Questions with no more context than this are likely to be closed.

Comment: The expression itself confuses me that it is in this form and I dont know how to approach the problem to start with. I tried watching youtube videos but I could not fins anything similar to that to help me understand put it in order in my hand. Hope I make any sense because english is not my mother language

Comment: Plus my school does not have a book for Math only notes that makes it harder

Comment: Do you understand what is meant by the $0-$level curve?

Comment: @AdityaGarg Thanks for fixing my edit.  I was trying to work out what I'd messed up.

Comment: I know that a level curve of a function is curve of points (x,y) where function have constant values. Does that mean that the points are 0?

Comment: Thank you for answering of course

Comment: Or means that the constant is 0?

Comment: By the $0-$level curve, they mean the solutions to $f(x,y)=0,$ so they're just saying that the graph of  $13y^2 + 7x^2+6\sqrt{3}xy+4y-4\sqrt{3}x=0$ is an ellipse.

Comment: Oooh okay thank you so much!! And what about center of it? Every youtube video or post I read had more info that they were given..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINITS**

Part a) of the problem is to put the equation  $$13y^2 + 7x^2+6\sqrt{3}xy+4y-4\sqrt{3}x=0$$ in so-called standard form, by rotating the axes and translating the origin.  It's hard to know what advice to give you on this, because you haven't indicated how much of this topic you understand.

When you look on the internet, you see lots of examples where the original equation doesn't have an $xy-$term.  In that case, rotation of the axes is not necessary.  Do you know how to deal with these problems when the $xy-$ term is lacking?  (The method is called "completing the square.")

The first step in doing these problems is to eliminate the $xy-$ term, and then to eliminate the $x-$ and $y-$ terms leaving an equation of the form $$\left({x-a\over A}\right)^2+\left({y-b\over B}\right)^2=1$$

If you haven't practiced eliminating the linear terms, that is the $x-$ and $y-$ terms from equations lacking an $xy-$term yet, I suggest you put this problem aside for the moment, and try the easier problems first.

**EDIT**

[Here](http://www.cengage.com/resource_uploads/downloads/1285060288_382318.pdf) is a brief introduction to rotation of axes, but it really says everything you need to know.  If that's not enough, Google "rotation of axes in an ellipse" and you'll get lots of hits.  The best way to use this site it to show us how far you've gotten, and where you'e stuck.  Then we'll be able to give you advice that's appropriate for you individually.

Comment: Yes I know how "completing the square" and ''eliminating the linear terms" works I have done it before. I dont have a mathematical mind if thats a way to say it. I know the pieces of the puzzle but putting them together I struggle with if you know what I mean. And thanks for the hint!